# What is the practical value of imaplib "close" & "logout"?

Tags: python, imaplib

I have a Python script that checks my email every few seconds for new emails in a `while` loop.

I connect to my email server using the `imaplib` library, in the following manner (the following code is at the top of the `while` loop):

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAPSERVER)
mail.login(userName, password)
mail.select(theFolderName, True)
return_code, mail_ids = mail.search(None, 'UnSeen')
```

Can someone tell me what the following statements actually do?

```
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4) they, respectively:

*"close currently selected mailbox"*

and

*"shutdown connection to server; returns server BYE response."*

But, what does it mean to "close" a mailbox and "shutdown" a connection? I mean, what is the point or benefit of these actions? Can you provide an example where these statements would in fact be necessary?

I ask this question because I notice absolutely no difference in my script whether these two lines are added or removed. So, I'd like to better understand their purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't notice any changes on your client or server with or without those last two statements, you should still call them anyway. [The IMAP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4) includes a handy diagram outlining the lifecycle of an IMAP connection (scroll one page up from that link):

> ```
>                +----------------------+
> ```

```
               |connection established|
               +----------------------+
                          ||
                          \/
        +--------------------------------------+
        |          server greeting             |
        +--------------------------------------+
                  || (1)       || (2)        || (3)
                  \/           ||            ||
        +-----------------+    ||            ||
        |Not Authenticated|    ||            ||
        +-----------------+    ||            ||
         || (7)   || (4)       ||            ||
         ||       \/           \/            ||
         ||     +----------------+           ||
         ||     | Authenticated  |<=++       ||
         ||     +----------------+  ||       ||
         ||       || (7)   || (5)   || (6)   ||
         ||       ||       \/       ||       ||
         ||       ||    +--------+  ||       ||
         ||       ||    |Selected|==++       ||
         ||       ||    +--------+           ||
         ||       ||       || (7)            ||
         \/       \/       \/                \/
        +--------------------------------------+
        |               Logout                 |
        +--------------------------------------+
                          ||
                          \/
            +-------------------------------+
            |both sides close the connection|
            +-------------------------------+
```

> ```
>      (1) connection without pre-authentication (OK greeting)
>      (2) pre-authenticated connection (PREAUTH greeting)
>      (3) rejected connection (BYE greeting)
>      (4) successful LOGIN or AUTHENTICATE command
>      (5) successful SELECT or EXAMINE command
>      (6) CLOSE command, or failed SELECT or EXAMINE command
>      (7) LOGOUT command, server shutdown, or connection closed
> ```

The spec goes into further details about how servers can try to behave when misbehaving clients talk to them but the safest thing to do is just follow the spec.

If for some reason you were adamantly against manually finishing IMAP connections as opposed to just exiting your script, you'd have to check out the implementation of the IMAP server you were talking with to figure out exactly how it handles that situation (which I assume could be summed up as "gracefully" but it's still a bad idea to rely on that behavior).

Comment: OK, good info. Is it better if I put the `mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAPSERVER)` and `mail.login(userName, password)` lines **before** the `while` loop or inside of it? In other words, should I simply connect once at the get-go and leave the same connection open for the duration of my script (which is 24/7), or should I reconnect/disconnect on every iteration of the `while` loop (which is every 3 seconds)?

Comment: Polling the mail server every 3 seconds is going to create a significant amount of load on the server. If you really want to poll that frequently, I'd try only calling `mail.select` in the loop (to avoid the overhead of constantly creating IMAP sessions and logging in). Note that the server will probably close your long-running session at some point so you should have some error logic that attempts to log in again when the connection is closed.

Comment: 1. I will follow your suggestions regarding finishing IMAP connections and regarding the location of the commands. Now that I think about it, for about 5% of the iterations, I've observed that my script will fail to check my email, giving the error message of either `Timed Out` or `IMAP4rev1 Server logging out`. I wonder if implementing your suggestions will prevent these errors from occurring.

Comment: 2. The server in question is Yahoo Mail. Is 3 seconds really that demanding, for a behemoth company like Yahoo? Wouldn't any standard email client application (like Outlook) be polling the servers about that often?

Comment: Personally, my email clients poll for email every 5 minutes to every 15 minutes (some of them might get push notifications when new mail arrives but that's beyond the scope of this question). While polling every 3 seconds is a drop in the bucket for Yahoo in the grand scheme of things, they may throttle or block you for that kind of usage.

Comment: 3 second reconnection is likely to get your IP rate limited or banned.